# React-Native-Maps: set Map Boundaries function is not accurate

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

I want to limit the region in which the user can scroll over the map. For this, I use the function

```
this.mapViewRef.current.setMapBoundaries(
        { latitude: 52.519972, longitude: 13.348412 },
        { latitude: 52.504231, longitude: 13.318503 }
      );
```

As a limitation I add northeast and southwest to the function. The map is limited, but the region I can scroll over is always larger than the area I specified. For example, the SouthWest point is 52.498114, 13.313054 instead of 52.504231, 13.318503.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

The `setMapBoundaries` method uses the lat/lng of the maps **center point** as it's marker. It does not stop the edges of the viewport itself from scrolling past the specified values.

So for instance, if you set your NE value as `latitude: 52.519972, longitude: 13.348412`, the **center** of the map will not be scrollable past that point.

Comment: Okay but in my opinion that have to be specified in the documentary, because it's double-edged

Comment: @J0na1han I created a pull request, you can track it here: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/pull/2707